# OR Preference changing with a return

Tags: php, operator-precedence, comparison-operators

From what I see operator precedence makes sense in these two examples:

```
$a = false;
$b = true;
$c = $a || $b;
```

Here $c is **true**

```
$a = false;
$b = true;
$c = $a or $b;
```

Here $c is **false**

---

I understand the reasoning behind it. However the following:

```
$a = false;
$b = true;
return $a or $b;
```

Returns true, which puzzles me.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: This is documented in [the manual for PHP operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).

Comment: @Qirel Where does it mention that operator precedence does not apply to return statements?

Comment: Operator precedence applies only to operators. `return` is not an operator. If that page explicitly listed everything that operator precedence **didn't** apply to, then it would be a few hundred pages long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`or` has lower precedence than `=`, so this:

```
$c = $a or $b;
```

Becomes this:

```
($c = $a) or $b;
```

But this doesn't make sense:

```
(return $a) or $b;
```

So you get this:

```
return ($a or $b);
```

Comment: But this is still no answer to the question right? Why does it return `$b`

Comment: It doesn't return `$b`, it returns `($a or $b)`. `false or true` is `true`.

Comment: @Gobbin Because `$a` is `false`…!?

Comment: As @Gobbin points out, the question is why. And "(return $a) or $b does not make sense" is not an answer, is it?

Comment: It's an answer if you understand that `return` is not an operator. @deceze explained it well in his answer. Think about the order of execution. If you evaluate `(return $a) or $b` then you'd `return $a` first, and then... what do you do with the `or $b` part? You can't do anything with it because you've already returned. I.e., it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I agree it does not make sense, but I was looking for a technical explanation and "PHP does A instead of doing B because B does not make sense" is not a technical explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Within an expression, operator precedence applies. `=`, `||` and `or` are all operators and `$c = $a or $b` is an expression. And according to operator precedence it evaluates as `($c = $a) or $b`.

However, `return` is a *statement*. `return` is not an operator and does not group by operator precedence. It always evaluates as `return <expression>`, and therefore always as `return ($a or $b)`.

The result of the *expression* `$c = $a or $b` is `true` BTW. `$c` is being assigned `false` in the course of the expression, but the expression overall returns the value `true` (`$b`). So even this would `return true`:

```
return $c = $a or $b;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It does make sense. However the result of the expression $c = $a or $b is not true. return $c = $a or $b does return true, but that is because, I think, php translates it into return ($c = $a) or $b;

Comment: The result of the ***entire*** expression `$c = $a or $b` **is `true`**. Sure, `$c` does not end up being `true`, but the expression result is. See https://3v4l.org/c6gqP.

Comment: Ah, I understood you wrong! Yea that makes sense. Thank you!